# What backend can I use to setup breeze properly on a mac?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, breeze

I would like to develop an AngularJS app with Breeze. I usually use NodeJS with Express but I hear it wont work with Breeze. All the example on breezejs.com use ASP.Net but i am on a mac and you can't run visual studio... What are my options ?

Comment: You can use ASP.NET on a mac, you just need to use mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

We are releasing a sample later today (in breeze v1.3.0) that shows Breeze talking to an arbitrary web service that could have been written on **any platform** using **any technology**.

Obviously, we need more of these examples and as importantly we need to show server side implementations of how one might write these web servivces to best leverage Breeze.  But... this is all definitely on our roadmap, and we are actively looking for partners in this process.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will you have a sample showing the integration with nodejs anytime soon ?

Comment: It's definitely on the roadmap.  Please add/vote for it here: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions. We use this to set our priorities.